# Disable new lines in bootstrap's navbar

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to make a bootstrap's navbar: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/lepumuviye/3/edit?html,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a>Item1</a></li>
                    <li><a>Item2</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Item3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a>Sub1</a></li>
                            <li><a>Sub2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem of the above code is that when we reduce the width of the preview, all the items move to different lines. However, I want them (except the submenu) to be always in the same line.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just display your `li` and `a` tags as `inline`, like this:

```
li {
  display: inline !important;
}

a {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

[image]

### Update

Here is the answers for questions in comments.

**1.** We can add classes to specific `li` tags (except `sub1` and `sub2` in your case), and apply `display: inline !important` only for `li`s with that classes.

**2.** Bootstrap automatically applies margins to `ul` tag, so just reset them or apply any values you like, for example:

```
ul {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you... there are two problems with your solution: 1) I don't want `sub1` and `sub2` to be displayed inline; 2) the paddings to the left and to the top change (one time) when we move the splitter and reduce the width of the preview, how could we avoid this?

Comment: @SoftTimur, 1) We can add classes to specific `li` tags (except `sub1` and `sub2` in your case), and apply `display: inline` only for `li`s with that classes. 2) Bootstrap automatically applies margins to `ul` tag, so just reset them or apply any values you like, for example: `ul {margin: 0 !important;}`

Comment: @SoftTimur, did it help you?

Comment: I tried to modify [the code](https://jsbin.com/sapovomoku/2/edit?html,output), when the width is not large the submenu still has problem. Can you make a working jsbin?

Answer (score 1):

This is default bootstrap's navbar style:

[image]

that caused when the width < 768px all the items move to different lines
To solve your problem, you can add it to your css:

`.nav>li {
  float: left;
}`

[Demo here](https://jsbin.com/zakawiguwe/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thank you... but when the width < 768px, is there a way to move `sub1` and `sub2` outside the bar?

Comment: "outside the bar"? what do you mean?